# Function dual to std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Let's assume I have a class with only one constructor:

```
class T {
 public:
  T(BigClass&& big) : big(std::move(big)) {}
  ...

  SomeBigClass
};
```

In most places the constructor is called on temporaries but in one place I need to make an explicit copy of BigClass because it is not a temporary and will be used multiple times in a loop:

```
void foo(const BigClass& big) {
  while (...) {
    T t(std::make_a_copy(big));
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there any function "dual" to `std::move` in C++11 or C++14 that would replace make_a_copy above ?

**Edit**: Some clarifications.

Comment: If you may need to make a copy then shouldn't you also supply a `T(BigClass const & big)` constructor and then invoke that instead?

Comment: Why do you need to make a copy of a *temporary*, instead of a move? That seems kinda non-sensical.

Comment: Someone should probably reject my edit.

Comment: If you want to write as few functions as possible, the two "core" are the copy constuctor, and `swap`.  Move constructor, copy assignment, and move assignment can be written in terms of copy constructor and swap.  Without a copy constructor... no shortcuts.

Comment: This question is quite unrelated to what the title says. The dual of `std::move` would be needed in a situation where you've got an rvalue reference expression and you need a _modifiable_ lvalue reference (which won't bind if you write it like that, and creating a temporary from the rvalue won't work either, because it can only initialise `const` lvalue references). That is not the case here, you have the exact opposite situation; it could be made to compile with `std::move` but that does not do what you want. The solution is to copy the `big` value first, which is unrelated to your `class T`.

Comment: In *this* example `foo(const BigClass&)` (const ref!) the move constrcutor *already* will *not* be invoked, as you cannot move out of a const object.

Comment: Question has a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543093/does-the-inverse-of-stdmove-exist) that provides additional infos.

Answer (score 5):

Why can't you just copy the `BigClass` object?

```
void foo(const BigClass& big) {
  while (...) {
    T t{ BigClass(big) };
    ...
  }
}
```

This makes a temporary `BigClass` that is then moved into the `T`

Comment: That doesn't look like it even needs the explicit copy.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes it does need the explicit copy; the question explicitly says the _unique_ constructor of `T` takes `BigClass&&`, in particular there is no constructor `T::T(const BigClass&)` whose use would create and bind the temporary for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to write:

```
template <typename T>
T make_temp(const T& x) { return x; }
```

There might be a standard function that happens to do that by accident when called with one argument, but there isn't one designed for this unusual pattern.

Answer (score -1):

If you can manipulate `T` you could template the constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B
{
  int x;
public:
  B (int i) : x(i) { }
  B (B && b) : x(b.x) { cout << "B moved (" << x << ")" << endl; }
  B (B const  & b) : x(b.x)  { cout << "B copied (" << x << ")" << endl; }
};


class A
{
  B b;
public:
  template<typename TB>
  A (TB && init_b) : b(std::forward<TB &&>(init_b)) { }
};

B foo (void) { B x(3); return x; }


int main (void)
{
  A a1(foo());
  B b1(4);
  A a2(b1);
  return 0;
}
```

Prints

> B moved (3)
>   B copied (4)

As far as I understand reference collapsing you should come out with a constructor `A(B&)` forwarding to the copy constructor of `B` and a `A(B&&)` forwarding to the move constructor of `B`.

Comment: Your test is deeply flawed. You copy `A` in the second line, which of course copies the `b` member. Also, a `std::forward<B>` will result in a move, only `std::forward<B&>` would result in an lvalue.

Comment: Well ok before the edit this was incorrect but the template solution using reference collapsing works for the specified case (as far as I can tell by check with `std::is_rvalue_reference` and `std::is_lvalue_reference`). So if there's still something wrong about that answer give me a hint instead of passing a downvote without any comments.